# HTML Input type of "button" fires almost exclusively after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this button:

```
<td style='width: 100px; align: left;'>
   <input type='button' value='Add Sched' style='font-weight: bold; 
   font-size: 11px; background-color: #696969; color: #FFFFFF; 
   padding: 0, 0, 0, 0; margin-right: 15px;' id='btnAddPS' name='btnAddPS' 
   alt='Add Period Schedule' 
   title='Add Period Schedule' onclick='psNewClick();' />
</td>
```

And its corresponding javascript function:

```
function psNewClick(){
   if(document.getElementById("pdEditor").style.display == "block")
      document.getElementById("pdEditor").style.display = "none";

   var psID = "";
   var psName = "";
   var psSeq = "99";

   document.getElementById("psName").value = psName;
   document.getElementById("psID").value = psID;

   document.getElementById("psAdd").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("psDel").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("psUpd").style.display = "none";

   document.getElementById("psEditor").style.display = "block";
};
```

My issue is after I submit an update of data and the page refreshes, this button has complete control over the webpage. If I click any other cell in my table (or within the form), the button highlights its border and presses down (always has focus?). There's even another input button that doesn't have this issue at the end of my form - it works normally (whether the problem button is on the page or not). When the page first loads, everything works as intended.

I've tried IE, Chrome and Firefox and I'm getting the issue in all three so I can only assume it is something with the code.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice you can offer up.

Comment: Sorry but, that's maybe my problem, I cannot understand what you want. As I understand, your problem is after page finished refreshing, `button` still maintain `down` status, right?

Comment: Not necessarily a down status. Just a mouse click anywhere on the form triggers the button, but only after submission which makes the page refresh. If I click the external link to come into the page, it works as expected.

Comment: If your problem was a small typographical error (as your answer indicates), please delete your question as it will likely not be helpful to other users.

Comment: I think the value of the lesson here is that if your inputs aren't working as expected, then double check that all tags - in your code and external file includes - have been properly closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, ironically, the issue was caused by an unclosed label tag in an include file used in our web apps for error handling. Once I removed that include line, the page worked as intended.